# Latest number of sequential records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm attempting to find the latest sequential number count from a record list.  I have the records in order and I've allocated a rank to them, and have flagged if the record is to be classed as sequential or not.

My issue is that I can't seem to work out how to stop the sequential count when a zero is reached ... so my end result in this example should equal 6.

My sample data looks like this, which is derived from :

```
SELECT top 100 percent
EDate, EDateID, RID, rNum, prev_rNum,               
CASE WHEN 
            prev_rNum IS NULL
            OR prev_rNum = rNum - 1
            OR prev_rNum = rNum
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS seqRec
FROM myTable
where RID = 7507
GROUP BY     EDate, EDateID, RID, rNum, prev_rNum
ORDER BY     EDate desc, EDateID desc
```

```
EDate | EDateID | RID | rNum | prev_rNum | seqRec

2023-12-03  14425   7507    1       1
2023-12-01  13422   7507    2   1   1
2023-11-19  13418   7507    3   2   1
2023-11-12  13413   7507    4   3   1
2023-11-11  13414   7507    5   4   1
2023-11-05  13412   7507    6   5   1
2023-10-14  13401   7507    8   6   0
2023-10-06  13400   7507    9   8   1
```

SQL Server 2019

Comment: I've *assumed* you are using SQL Server here; in your are in fact using SyBase, then please update your question to correct the tag(s) accordingly.

Comment: instead of stopping the sequence, you can add a new column(result) with check if seqRec is zero then add prev_rNum value

Comment: What do you want to return if sequence look like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10. ALso, most importantly, what do you *need* this for, i have a feeling your actual problem shouldn't be solved by sequence looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

We will only select the row with seqRec = 0 and among all the rows with seqRec = 0 for a RID, we will select the row with MIN(prev_rNum). This will give us latest sequential number count from a record list.

```
SELECT RID, MIN(prev_rNum) latest_sequential_number_count 
FROM (

SELECT 
        EDate, EDateID, RID, rNum, prev_rNum,               
        CASE WHEN 
                    prev_rNum IS NULL
                    OR prev_rNum = rNum - 1
                    OR prev_rNum = rNum
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS seqRec
        FROM myTable
        -- where RID = 7507
        GROUP BY     EDate, EDateID, RID, rNum, prev_rNum
) sub 
WHERE seqRec = 0
GROUP BY RID
```

Comment: Hi - yes, that works really well actually. But now I see something that I hadn't considered before, and that's the first rNum within each group must be equal 1, as that denotes records from the very latest 'event'.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to find the longest consecutive sequence. If that's the case, you have a **gaps and islands** problem, which can be resolved by calculating the difference between the row numbers and the running total to obtain groups of sequences.

```
WITH mytable AS (
          SELECT top 100 percent
          EDate, EDateID, RID, rNum, prev_rNum,               
          CASE WHEN 
                            prev_rNum IS NULL
                            OR prev_rNum = rNum - 1
                            OR prev_rNum = rNum
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS seqRec
          FROM myTable
          where RID = 7507
          GROUP BY EDate, EDateID, RID, rNum, prev_rNum
),
cte AS (
   SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EDate DESC) 
           - SUM(seqRec) OVER(ORDER BY EDate DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grp
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT top 1 COUNT(*) Total
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY count(1) DESC
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/v0RIvkKl)